# clearing error_log or php_error

Tags: php, error-log

I use the error_log() function while debugging using Wamp server offline - it prints to a file called php_error.log along with any errors that are generated by bugs in the code. As errors accumulate, from bugs or from debugging error_log commands the file gets bigger.  I find myself using select all, delete and save all the time to clear the file and keep the size usable.  Is there a php command to clear the log or to start it from scratch rather than appending the new text.  Thanks.

Comment: Not really - this shows how to delete the whole file from the command line.  I just want to use error_log within php with the effect that the file is a cleared first or not appended to an already long one.

Comment: Why not use [`unlink()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)?

Comment: Perhaps write your own errors that you create via error_log to a different file to begin with? That file name could even be created based on the current date/time or something.

Comment: Thanks kmoser, yes, that's perfect, I will write a function that takes a parameter so i can use error_log in 'append mode' or in clear 'clear first' mode.

Comment: Thanks CBroe - yes, that's a good idea, I can send my intended debug text to a special file and not worry about the default file getting too long.  Thanks.